# Output Placeholder, Max Length, Line Breaks, Initial Rows values for Fields in Sprout Forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to create a dynamic form that loops through all the form fields and dynamically applies the HTML that matches the field type.

I can't seem to find what to use to output: Placeholder, Max Length, Line Breaks, Initial Rows.

Other values like `field.type`, `field.required`, `field.handle` work fine. But trying `field.placeholder` or `field.settings.placeholder` does not work.

```
{% set fields = tab.getFields() %}

{% for field in fields %}

    {% set required = field.required %}
    {% set field = field.getField() %}

    {% if field.type == "PlainText" %}
        <input type="text" name="fields[{{ field.handle }}]" value="{{ attribute(submittedEntry, field.handle) }}" placeholder="">
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due you're trying to get a property from the [FieldLayoutModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/FieldLayoutModel) instead of [FieldLayoutFieldModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/FieldLayoutFieldModel) please see the code bellow to fix the error.

```
{%- set layoutFields = tab.getFields() %}

    {% for layoutField in layoutFields -%}

        {%- set field     = layoutField.getField() -%}
        {{ field.settings.placeholder }}
    {% endfor %}
```